# TDateTimePicker delphi get year and month

Tags: delphi, datetimepicker

I have a SP built in SQL that has 2 param, one is year and the other one is month.

In delphi I added a TDateTimePicker on a frame in order to let the user pick the month and the year.

How do I retrie the values of the Year/Day from TDateTimePicker?

I've tried `DateTimePicker2.Date;` but this gives me a date in format "xx/xx/xxxx"

I want to get the actual Year/month

something like

```
int year ;
year :=  DateTimePicker2.Date.Year;
```

Is there any way I can achieve this ?

Comment: Use [`YearOf`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.DateUtils.YearOf) and [`MonthOf`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.DateUtils.MonthOf) functions. Or [`DecodeDate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.SysUtils.DecodeDate) to get them at once.

Comment: Thank you sir! I knew there were functions to do this, but I could not find them.

Comment: You want to make that an answer @TLama?

Comment: @Andy_D, nope, sorry. I've no time to write some fairy tale to that sencence :-) Feel free to post one...

Comment: Downvoter, please say why you downvoted the question.

Comment: this is usefull question. "science are endless even if you have mastered"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As TLama said you can use the `DecodeDate` function like this :-

```
Var
  lDay,
  lMonth,
  lYear : Word;
Begin
  DecodeDate(DateTimePicker2.Date, lDay, lMonth, lYear);
  MyStoredProc.Params[0].AsInteger := lDay;
  MyStoredProc.Params[1].AsInteger := lMonth;
  MyStoredProc.Execute;
End;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `YearOf()` and `MonthOf()` functions in `DateUtils`

You code will be:

```
year := YearOf(DateTimePicker1.Date);
month := MonthOf(DateTimePicker1.Date);
```

If the value in the `DateTimePicker1.Date` is `27/8/2015`
then the value of  year is 2015 and month is 8.